# Передать значение переменной из Python в bash скрипт

Tags: python

```
import subprocess
Python_arg = 456
subprocess.Popen('/path/script.sh 123 "Python_arg"', shell=True)
```

Передаются аргументы `123` и `Python_arg`.

А должно быть `123` и `456`.

Как правильно сделать синтаксис?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать c помощью метода `format` класса `string`:

```
subprocess.Popen('/path/script.sh 123 {0}'.format(Python_arg), shell=True)
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, вы мне очень помогли) Все верно - только там нужно указать не `{1}` а `{0}`